# Why does YouTube fullscreen freeze my Ubuntu desktop?

Tags: ubuntu, freeze, youtube

Sometimes when I enlarge a video to full screen, the entire system freezes. It continues to play audio with the first frame of the video displayed on the screen, but the desktop is stuck and the system takes no keyboard/mouse input. I have to reboot the entire system to fix it. This happens to ~50% of the videos I watch. I have Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS running Google Chrome. Any ideas about what's causing this?

Comment: I would try with a different browser to exclude the browser having problems, boot from a live Ubuntu flash drive to see if the behaviour is the same. Could be the graphic card?! Does it happen when you play a fullscreen video with another app? eg VLC or something similar. Are you able to get into the virtual terminal with CTRL + ALT + (F1 to F7) - the switch may enable the graphic one. Check for errors in log files.

Comment: Dedicated server? No input? Dedicated servers are designed to run at optimum with nothing else running except vitals -- could be on purpose. Is the computer yours? OpenSource my friend. It's a manual process of installing the correct drivers and plugins. How old is your computer and what type of RAM would you have and how much? Sounds like you are using an oldie, but not goodie perhaps and need to invest. I have an older laptop with a Linux OS that I never use unless I need it for a project for school that requires Linux compiling for programs.

Comment: @Zina I'll give it a try with Firefox and see if that improves it. It doesn't do it with VLC or Netflix, but did with Facebook embeded videos since I posted this.

Comment: @ejbytes I have 4GB of RAM. The computer is a HP Pavilion Sleekbook from 2012 that used to run Windows 8 before I swapped it out for Linux. It never dropped videos with Windows so I don't believe it's in the hardware. I don't think it's an age issue because it works great for everything else and can run non-YouTube/Facebook videos fine. A driver seems very likely, I just don't know how to go about fixing that.

Comment: What flavour or Linux? I tried about 3 of them until I found one that I liked. There are two sides, Debian and Fedora. Look it up, try a couple and see which one fits your needs. I too have a Pavilian HP, but in Desktop with 10GB RAM and it came with Win 8.1. I gave it 3 months and I bought Win 7 Pro after that. Mind you, I had to use my laptop to download drivers from the correct "hardware spec" websites for Win 7. After that it worked great! I bought a Surface Pro 4 with an add on purchase of MS NoteOne for school with Win10 pro. Win 10 pro is far better than 8.1 and I like it so far.